# Removing currency symbol and replacing comma with point using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the currency symbol and replacing the comma in digit with point using javascript regex. 
I have value like this;

199,00 kr

I want to make it like
199.00

I used this script but its not working fine.

```
val.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

Using this I am able to remove the currency but it also makes the output as
19900

I tried this way

```
var val2 = val.replace(/,/g, '.')
var val2 = val2.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

But again it makes the output as 19900

Please advise what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The second regex also removed the . of the first one.

Comment: No need for a regex: `'199,00 kr'.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '.')`

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest regex for this case can be:

```
'199,00 kr'.replace(/(\d+),(\d+).*/, '$1.$2')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
result = subject.replace(/(\d+),(\d+)[\s\S]*/g, "$1.$2");
```

Comment: It gives `199.00 kr`

Comment: @hsz Thank you, I fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna split the string by commas, then replace each substring and then join by dot, that way you won't remove commas or dots during replacement:

```
 val.split(",").map(str => str.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')).join(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the digits in a capturing group and match the dot and the whitespace followed by `kr`. Use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\'b`at the start and at the end.

In the replacement use group1, dot, group 2: `$1.$2`

```js
var val2 = "199,00 kr";
val2 = val2.replace(/\b(\d+),(\d+)\s*kr\b/g, '$1.$2');
console.log(val2);
```

Comment: And it gives `199,00`

Comment: @hsz You are right, I missed the dot part. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This version scans a text for anything looking like a currency and runs the replacer function on it.

This is easy to modify for future edge cases.

```js
function fixPrices(txt) {
  return txt
    .replace(/\d*\,*\d* kr\b/igm, function(subject) {
      return subject
        .replace(",", '.')
        .replace("kr", '')
        .trim();
    });
}
//TEST
var txt = "Hej min is koster 199,00 kr, men er det ikke lidt meget?\nJeg syntes den b\u00F8r koste 20 kr, 20,5 kr eller bare ,5 kr!";
console.log(txt);
console.log(fixPrices(txt));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more flexible alternative (doesn't handle +/- sign):

```js
const extractNumber = s => s.replace(/\D+/g, m => m == ',' ? '.' : ''); 

console.log( extractNumber('199,00 kr') )        // "199.00"
console.log( extractNumber('199 kr') )           // "199"
console.log( extractNumber('123.456,00 kr') )    // "123456.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a chance on a npm library:

```js
import currencyToFloat from 'currency-to-float';

const price = '199,99 kr';

const parsed = currencyToFloat(price);

console.log(parsed); // 199.99
```